# Sporadic problems with IPv4 not available via Ethernet: how to diagnose the culprit?

Tags: networking, ethernet

I have Ubuntu 16.04.

From time to time LAN link does not function properly right from the boot. Chrome complains that DNS is not available; I cannot access the router using its IP address (192.168.1.1).

Earlier, it did not happen too often. When it happened, I used to disable and re-enable Wire Network 1 via Network indicator, and everything worked again after that. Now it happens almost every time, and the trick with the Network indicator does not work anymore, so I have to reboot, sometimes more than once.

`ifconfig` outputs this when everything works correctly:

```
enp0s31f6 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 1c:1b:0d:95:42:3a  
          inet addr:192.168.1.40  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5a8d:6caa:becd:f3a1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3565117 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4478388 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1861499120 (1.8 GB)  TX bytes:4973111428 (4.9 GB)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:f7100000-f7120000
```

And for a 'broken' case it's

```
enp0s31f6 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 1c:1b:0d:95:42:3a  
          inet6 addr: fe80::5a8d:6caa:becd:f3a1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:35 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:420 (420.0 B)  TX bytes:6160 (6.1 KB)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:f7100000-f7120000
```

The difference is the following line

```
inet addr:192.168.1.40  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

which is absent for the 'broken' case. Looks like in such a case, the interface does not get an IPv4 address, although it gets an IPv6 address.

`dmesg` output does not contain anything suspicious (or I just cannot spot it).

The question is: how do I diagnose the problem? Any logs or tools that could be useful? And how do I 'reinitialize' the interface (if this is possible) to make it try to pick up IPv4 again without a reboot?